# iOS5 content view controller blocks scroll view on custom container view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, parent-child, ioc-container

for backward compatibility to iOS5 I cannot use the Custom View feature of storyboarding.

I have a view controller that has on top a horizontal scroll menu. The scroll view consists of several buttons each of which shows different contents in different ways so I want a child view controller for each content to show.

This image explains better what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Following the Apple's developer guide I tried to add the content view controller as child of the main view controller. As soon as the child view controller is presented the scroll view with the buttons menu stopped scrolling. I got stuck on this problem and I don't know why.

Here is the code:

MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    self.menuScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, kScrollViewMarginTop, self.view.frame.size.width, kScrollViewHeight);
    self.menuScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.menuScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;


    self.firstMenuButton.selected = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.menuScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(kScrollViewContentWidth, kScrollViewHeight);
}

- (IBAction)menuButtonTapped:(id)sender{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    switch (button.tag) {
        case 0:
            if (![self.firstMenuButton isSelected]) {
                self.firstMenuButton.selected = YES;
                [self.firstMenuButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstMenuButton_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                [self deselectButtonsExceptButtonWithTag:button.tag];

                //Shows the first content
                UIViewController *contentViewController = (UITableViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstControllerStoryboardID"];
                [self displayContentViewController:contentViewController];
            }
            break;

      default:
            break;
    }   
}

- (void)displayContentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{


    [self addChildViewController:viewController];

    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.menuScrollView.frame.origin.y + self.menuScrollView.frame.size.height + 5.0, 320.0, 200.0);

    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

I tried to achieve it in iOS6 with storyboarding and it works, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is really appreciated
Cheers

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Does the content controller's view look like it's supposed to, and can you interact with it normally?

Comment: yes the content view controller is  a table view controller which I can interact with normally. I don't know why I cannot scroll the menu after adding the content view controller child

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem disabling the AutoLayout option from the Storyboard